# Laravel: how to run seeder with relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-seeding

Why "relationship" in my seeder code isn't working?  It inserts to User model without any problem.  But doesn't  insert anything to UserMeta model. There is not even any error.
I have tested this code in controller.  It was functioning fine with "relationship"

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\User;
use App\UserMeta;

class MyUsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Auto generated seed file.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        if (User::count() == 0) {

            $user = User::create([
                'name'           => 'Admin',
                'email'          => 'admin@admin.com',
                'password'       => bcrypt('password'),
                'remember_token' => str_random(60),
            ]);

            $user_meta = new UserMeta([
                'meta_key' => 'role',
                'meta_value' => 'admin',
            ]);
            $user->UserMeta()->save($user_meta);
        }
    }
}
```

Model User

```
public function UserMeta()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\UserMeta', 'user_id');
}
```

Model UserMeta

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

users table

```
       Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

usermeta table

```
        Schema::create('usermeta', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('user_meta_id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('meta_key');
            $table->string('meta_value');
        });
```

Comment: show you both model relationships

Comment: does the user table has usermeta_id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `usermeta` migration to

```
Schema::create('usermeta', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('user_meta_id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

    // add foreign key constraint
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

    $table->string('meta_key');
    $table->string('meta_value');
});
```

and re-run your migrations.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
$user_meta = new UserMeta([
                'meta_key' => 'role','user_id'=>$user_id,
            ]);
$user_meta->user_id=$user->id;
$user_meta->save();
```

Comment: I introduced the table in the model. protected $table = 'usermeta';

Comment: Removed mention to naming convention fro my answer